Does human sensitivity to radiation impose a maximum distance on interstellar voyages regardless of radiation shielding or speed?
The duration of crewed interstellar voyages is potentially limited by exposure to interstellar radiation.

radiation dose obtained in a non-relativistic space module moving in
interstellar space would be, approximately, 70 rems/year
https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0610030
The dose of radiation expected to cause death to 50 percent of an
exposed population within 30 days ... is in the range from 400 to 450 rem
https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/basic-ref/glossary/lethal-dose-ld.html

Although estimates of lethal chronic doses of radiation are based on scant evidence, the duration of interstellar voyages would appear to be limited to a decade or two unless radiation exposure can be reduced or radiation tolerance increased.
Increasing the spacecraft’s shielding mass reduces acceleration, which prolongs a voyage of a given distance and therefore prolongs radiation exposure duration. This produces a trade-off where increasing shielding does not extend the maximum distance of a radiation-limited voyage.
The strategy of shortening  the voyage duration by increasing the spacecraft to relativistic velocity suffers from a similar trade-off.

The most dangerous is interstellar gas, which acts as a flow nucleonic
radiation bombarding a relativistic starship. Radiation flux is
extremely high even for moderate relativistic velocities … The
presence of a neutral component in interstellar gas excludes the
implementation of magnetic shielding alone.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0610030
The strategy of increasing crew radiation tolerance by genetic engineering does not suffer these trade-offs.
Genetic engineering of humans is obviously a complex undertaking, on the same level of difficulty as developing interstellar propulsion. If the effective range of interstellar voyages is limited by both radiation sensitivity and delta-v, it makes sense to pursue solutions to both problems.
Humans are obviously not yet ready for interstellar voyages, but enhanced radiation resistance would be an advantage even within the solar system.
Tardigrades are small aquatic animals with remarkable resistance to radiation.
https://www.newscientist.com/article/2106468-worlds-hardiest-animal-has-evolved-radiation-shield-for-its-dna

Tardigrades apparently owe a large part of their radiation tolerance to “Dsup”, a protein which protects DNA from a variety of damaging agents. The gene coding for Dusp was genetically engineered into cultured human kidney cells. This markedly reduced radiation-induced DNA damage.
Other studies https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6770827 suggest DNA repair mechanisms present in Tardigrades enhance the radiation resistance provided by Dusp.

Recent studies show that stress-related tardigrade genes may be
transfected to human cells and provide increased tolerance to osmotic
stress and ionizing radiation. With the recent sequencing of the
tardigrade genome, more studies applying tardigrade omics to relevant
aspects of human medicine are expected.

These findings hint at the possibility of genetically engineered space-faring humans with significantly improved radiation tolerance. For multigeneration voyages, the proposed genetic changes would be transmitted to succeeding generations.
The most common malignancy induced by radiation is leukemia, particularly AML. If myeliod stem cells could be genetically engineered to be more radiation resistant (perhaps by the production of Dusp) there is the potential for reduced incidence of leukemia or, perhaps, more robust recovery from the treatment of leukemia.
The proposed genetic engineering could be performed in vitro, with the enhanced cells returned to the donor. Germ cells (reproductive cells) would not be modified in this process.

Well, you first! The problem is what else, in a very complex system, inserting and turning on that gene does. Is it conceivable that gene (or something else) might help? Sure. It is also conceivable that there will be subtle or dramatic impacts to other things.

I think we will need to build a generation ship, and that ship will be so huge that its hull will probably be able to provide adequate radiation shielding. But if we were to master genetic engineering, we would likely be much more successful at seeding other worlds with life from Earth - including humans.

Given that interstellar travel is impossible at the present time, nobody can say what limitations might apply if it ever becomes possible.

@JohnDoty ... people certainly thought about travelling to the Moon before it became possible. In fact, it would have never happened if it had not been thought about.

@phil1008 ... The point I was attempting to make: if shielding mass limits acceleration (and therefor velocity) and total radiation dose (rate times voyage duration) limits voyage duration, perhaps there is a fundamental limitation to the distance humans can travel no matter how many generations they take to do it.

@phil1008 ... However, if the mass of the shielding increases with the square while ship volume increases with the cube of ship size, maybe a very large generation ship could break this shielding/acceleration relationship.

Yes, that's what I was thinking. To make it between stars you'd probably need a self-sustaining ecosystem in a ship - which would be pretty huge I think.

@JonCuster...Quite right.  Naturally occurring genes seldom perform only one function at one time in an organism's life. Genetics is not computer code. There is wide variation in radiation resistance between organism, even between mammals. Some animals have evolved radiation resistance far beyond levels which they were exposed to in their natural environment. There is evidence that some "radiation resistance" genes evolved for resistance to DNA damage to desiccation, not radiation.  Our knowledge of human genetic engineering is on the same level as our understanding of interstellar propulsion.

@Woody The details of lunar travel needed working out in a context where they were practical. Early speculations didn't match the actual Moon landings very well.

@Woody: I don't think a ship on a 1000-year voyage would require significantly more shielding than a ship on a 100-year voyage, since we only care about how much radiation a person receives within a single lifetime. (Obviously we're talking about generation ships for that kind of time scale.) Or are you worried about genetic damage accumulating over generations? Regardless, there's always a limit beyond which additional shielding is unnecessary -- for instance, if you've got the radiation down to Earth background levels, then you won't need more shielding even if you 10x the voyage time.

There is a seemingly valid assumtion here that we have three options

Slow. Many years of radiation. Death.
Fast. Low mass and thus low shields. Death.
Reletavistic. Generating own problems. Death.

I would like to challenge option 1.   The Earth is a heavily shielded (and slow) space object. We still receive daily radiation, but at a low enough level the body can deal wit that.
So heavily shielded, and slow will get us a long range.  If we bring enough genetic variance (read: million-ish people) then we can go as far as the spaceship lasts.
Which is not infinite unless you stop to harvest fresh resources along the way. And dreadfully slow.  And you need a huge vessel with plenty redundancy.
So I guess there is an answer; Long to infinity. But to damn slow.

Nicely said, Hennes. But it doesn't address the possibility of increasing human radiation tolerance. SE tends to be hardware oriented. The solution to this interstellar conundrum may be wetware engineering. Your comment about a "million-ish people" implies that natural selection could provide a solution. Genetic engineering may get the same result, but sooner.

The Starlost (what happens when you don't have sufficiently "plenty redundancy")

Re starlost.  It has been decades since I read that.    Re natural selection I was not trying to answer that, I was heading to a sufficient big ark ship which I realise is has several disadvantages. In this content speed.   So if we do not modify humans the range stilll is long, but at a horrible cost in resources (cost to build the ship) and in time (due to slow).

Self Shielding
I doubt radiation will be a limiting factor on an interstellar  journey, because any conceivable interstellar ship will be massive.
Just as an order of magnitude look, let's think about food for 10 people on a 40 year trip.
Using 2 MREs at 600 grams each per person per day, we're looking at:

2 * 10 * 365 * 40 * 0.6 = 175,200kg or over 175 tonnes of food

If the living area of the ship is a 10x10x10 meter cube, you'd have about 300kg per square meter of shielding, just from stored food.
Now Expand That
So then we need to look into power sources, atmosphere control, water, waste management, recycling, spare parts, manufacturing capabilities, and dozens of other issues that will need to be solved.
Every single one of those is going to add to the mass budget.
And all of that is going to be shielding for the crew. Because equipment is very radiation tolerant, and people just aren't.
Going Fast
Increasing the speed actually makes this problem easier, because it means that the incoming radiation is going to be directional - it will primarily come from the front of the ship. Now you can design around putting storage up front and people in the back.
In the end, interstellar ships are going to be so huge, you can just use the rest of the ship as the shielding for the crew.

I think the point that you make is valid, but some deep space radiation such as Fe56+ are very penetrating. The radiation levels inside the shield actually increases beyond a certain threshold thickness before eventually falling again dues to secondary and tertiary radiation showers from the impact of a single primary particle.

@Slarty - I hear you, but I don't think it's feasible to build a manned interstellar probe that is smaller than 100,000s of tonnes. With an aircraft carrier's worth of mass, you can do some pretty significant shielding.

Yes this is true, Although the whole proposition starts to unravel weight wise very quickly. An aircraft carriers worth of tonnage for the ship (which presumably would need to be spun to provide artificial gravity) is just the start. The tyranny of the rocket equation would mean that the propellant required to slow the ship down on arrival would outweigh the ship by a very large margin and an even vaster ;o) amount would be needed to accelerate the whole ship and all its deceleration propellant in the first place. Bottom line your argument is correct, but the whole idea is not practical.

Wouldn’t eating that food bombarded with radiation for years be an issue? But I would be surprised if people set off on such a long mission with all the food from the start, wouldn’t there rather be some way to create/grow the food on the way?

@jcaron - eating food bombarded with neutron radiation would be bad, but in this case, it would be gamma radiation, which should be fine.

@jcaron - For growing food: I agree, that seems unlikely they'd go with MREs -- I'm using them as a lower limit. I expect that growing food would be even heavier since it would require grow lights, soil, water, processing, including storing surplus and having some way of recovering from a crop failure. Which only strengthens the point -- all that mass is shielding, which makes it easier to manage radiation for the crew. The complexities of the food system are a much bigger engineering challenge than radiation management!

Radiation is just one of many almost impossibly difficult interdependent problems. The primary issue is one of the vast distance that must be covered. To overcome the distance requires traveling at high speed for a long time. Human occupants will take up a lot of mass and a lot of mass requires a vast amount of propellant. Trying to build massive radiation shielding for such a vessel only exacerbates the mass problem.
In a nutshell human interstellar voyages are not a practical proposition now and may never be. Radiation is just one more giant issue to deal with.
